# MvcMailer Areas and _Layout Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, sendmail, area, mvcmailer

I am using [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer) for sending email in my project.

everything OK but when I send email in admin area, email is sent with admin area layout, and It doesn't use "~/View/UserMailer/_Layout.cshtml".

In Github of this project, [some one discuss this issue](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/32) but no one didn't has  answered.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the _Layout.cshtml in your mailer folder to something else such as _LayoutMailer.cshtml

Rename the MasterName in your mailer constructor in `UserMailer.cs` to the same as follows:

```
public class UserMailer : MailerBase
{
    public UserMailer()
    {
        MasterName = "_LayoutMailer";
    }
    ...
}
```